# Display Date with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

This is my date 20100816 and it integer date.

How to display it like 08/16/2010?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Date.strptime` method to read a date in a given format and `strftime` to print it out in another format:

```
require 'date'
intdate = 20100816
Date.strptime(intdate.to_s, "%Y%m%d").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
#=> "08/16/2010"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Date.parse` method and `strftime` to format the date

```
Date.parse(20100816.to_s).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Date class is the most elegant solution.  Another approach is to deal with it as a string:

```
d = 20100820
e = d.to_s
f = [e[4..5], e[6..7], e[0..3]].join('/')
```